# Paths declared in tsconfig do not resolve properly without index.ts in import

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make the clean imports work in my project. I figured out most of it, but it still does not resolve the way it should. Here's a simplified version of the problem

folder structure:

```
src/
├── core/
│   ├── app.ts
│   └── index.ts
└── main.ts
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "paths": {
            "@core/*": ["core/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

src/core/app.ts:

```js
export class App {
    // code
}
```

src/main.ts

```js
import { App } from './core';       // Works
import { App } from './core/app';   // Works
import { App } from './core/index'; // Works

import { App } from '@core';       // Cannot find module '@core/'. ts(2307)
import { App } from '@core/app';   // Works
import { App } from '@core/index'; // Works
```

Comment: Does adding `"@core": ["core"]` to `paths` help?

Comment: Nope, it does not seem to help

Comment: hmm.. have a look at this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/so-57540642-k6126 . I don't have any compiler issues.

Comment: Oh, I see my error. It does work now. Thank you. As far as I know, Angular does just fine with `"@core/*": ["core/*"]` without the duplicated entry... but maybe it's something in angular that helps to resolve it. Anyway, this works so thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you can change your file tsconfig.json to:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
        "@core*": ["core*"]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).